# How should I resolve 'Bad Request (400)' error after mapping domain by configuring load balancer in GCP?

Tags: google-cloud-run, domain-mapping, gcp-load-balancer

I am trying to map a domain name for google cloud run service running in 'asia-south1' region. But as per cloud run domain mapping [limitations](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains#limitations) it is not possible use cloud run domain mappings in 'asia-south1' region.

So document suggested to set up a custom domain by configuring an [HTTP(s) load balancer](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless)

I did that configuration but both ip address and mapped domain to ip address are throwing 'Bad Request (400)' error.

What mistake I have made? How should I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show what you configured in your question. Pointing to a guide does not help as we do not know if you followed the guide correctly.

Comment: Hi Sir, thanks for the reply! Issue has been solved. I have configured load balancer correctly but static ip address was not added in 'ALLOWED_HOSTS', I did that and deployed new revision. Everything is working fine. Thanks again for your time.